# SetLayeredWindowAttributes not work well in LWA_COLORKEY mode in a WinUI 3 application

Tags: winapi, winui-3

https://github.com/ACGNnsj/WinUI3CppWinRTDemo/blob/master/OCR/MainWindow.xaml.cpp

https://github.com/ACGNnsj/WinUI3CppWinRTDemo/blob/master/OCR/OCROverlay.xaml

The `LWA_ALPHA` mode works well, while the `LWA_COLORKEY` mode does not. However, return values of both cases are non-zero.

I've tried to make either background color or border color transparent, but neither of them worked.

I wonder whether the issue is related to misconfiguration, or something like rendering?

Comment: `lExStyle ^= WS_EX_LAYERED;` should be `lExStyle |= WS_EX_LAYERED;` instead. If `WS_EX_LAYERED` is already enabled beforehand, then `^=` will disable it, which you don't want, as you can't use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` without `WS_EX_LAYERED`, so checking `(lExStyle & WS_EX_LAYERED)` makes no sense to do unless you attach `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` to the `if`, eg: `if (lExStyle & WS_EX_LAYERED) { ... bool result = SetLayeredWindowAttributes(...); ... }`

Comment: Thanks, guy. You get a point here. Bit flags should work with bitor rather than xor. Unfortunately, that seems not to be the real issue, since the LWA_ALPHA mode worked and I've tried bitor before.

Comment: If `WS_EX_LAYERED` is enabled but `LWA_COLORKEY` is not working, then most likely you are simply specifying the wrong color value.